# Как в библиотеке Pygame в Python плавно повернуть изображение?

Tags: python, pygame

Я хочу чтобы мое изображение при удерживании определенной клавиши поворачивалось.

```
def __init__(self, x, y, w=100, h=100):
    super(Car, self).__init__()
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(car_image, 180)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
    self.speed = speed
    self.reversing = False

def update(self):
    #if 0 <= self.rect.y <= heidth and 0 <= self.rect.x <= whidth:

    if forward:
        self.rect.y += 10
    if back:
        self.rect.y -= 10
    if left:
```

---

Прошу строго не судить. Это мой первый вопрос)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример реализации поворота изображения при зажатой кнопки (пробел):

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

image = pygame.image.load('IMAGE.png')
image_rect = image.get_rect(center=(width // 2, height // 2))

rotation_angle = 0
rotation_speed = 2

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        rotation_angle += rotation_speed
    
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, rotation_angle)
    rotated_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=image_rect.center)
    
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(rotated_image, rotated_rect)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Устанавливаем изначальный угол поворота на 0.

Проверяем циклом зажата ли клавиша K_SPACE.

Если клавиша зажата, то угол поворота меняется на значение, указанное в rotation_speed.

Comment: Если у Вас возникнут дополнительные вопросы, задавайте их в комментариях.
Поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку решения на данный ответ, если он решит Вашу проблему. 
Удачных разработок!